# jQuery sortable list placeholder issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a sortable list. I have managed to sort into multilevel. But when an element from first level depth is inserted into second level depth the placeholder keeps running violently.

```
$('.sortable').sortable({ 
    connectWith:    '.sortable',
    cursor:         'move',
    placeholder:    'sortable-placeholder',
    handle:         '.block-title',
    cursorAt:       { left: 150, top: 17 },
    /*tolerance:      'pointer',*/
    scroll:         false,
    zIndex:         9999,
});
$('.sortable').disableSelection();
```

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/melvinstanly/c7PGP/61/)

Comment: I'm having no problems with it, including when I move a level 1 item to level 2. Chrome v67 here. An item flutters a bit when moving. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @VictorStoddard when you move `index` into `services` , don't you see it ?

Comment: @VictorStoddard when you place `index` exactly over `support` it is not showing near by placeholder but instead showing far away placeholder

Comment: It's smooth. The only problem is that I can't move Index between Services and Design -- but I can move it above design if I drag it from below.

Comment: Ok, I see that. the placeholder isn't staying aligned vertically. I thought that was desired so that you could read the text underneath. Do you want that to stop?

Comment: @VictorStoddard yes. But sorting shouldn't be cancelled

Comment: When moving index above support, its showing the placeholder below because that is the last Tier 2 item so its giving the option to drop into Tier 1.  If you move up slightly it gives you the option to drop as Tier3.   If you adjust slightly from there, the placeholder moves to indicate dropping in that location would place the item in Tier 2.    It is working as intended (though the gui gets a little flakey at times).   Since an item can be placed, in this example, in Tier 1, Teir 2, or Teir 3,  that is why you see the different placeholder locations.

Comment: @BrianPatterson Is there an option to remove that flakey behaviour

Comment: You can try tweaking the CSS, or adding and removing hover properties and modifying behavior like that.   Or use a different widget like YUI or something.  https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/sortable/

Comment: @BrianPatterson tweaking css doesn't seem good

Comment: @BrianPatterson Isn't there any solution for jquery ui ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the specific version of jquery/jquery ui. On `jquery-1.9.1/ui-1.9.2` the problem with flickering disappeared:

https://jsfiddle.net/x2dnmL0j/

---

UPDATE: 
If you cannot get rid of old jquery you can use the old/new jquery versions in parallel. New jquery will be accessible under another namespace. See: [jquery.noconflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    //This means that jquery  declared first  will be maintained with standard namespace and last one will get the name $3.
    var $3 = jQuery.noConflict(true)

    console.log("old:",$.fn.jquery, $.ui.version)
    console.log("new:",$3.fn.jquery, $3.ui.version)

    </script>

</head>
```

Comment: This was a sample of my actual program. But this didn't solve issue in my actual program. Also changing the version is not the solution i wanted.

Comment: But now you know that this is obviously a ui bug of a legacy version of jquery which is now fixed. As far as the ability to use multiple versions of jquery/ui see my updated answer.

Comment: What you mean by fixed ? I see the same flickering issue when using 1.12.1 and 1.11.4 (ui)

Comment: I don't see any flickering here: https://jsfiddle.net/x2dnmL0j/3/  Ok when I said a ui bug I did not mean a jquery-ui bug, I meant a ui bug in jquery. I don't really know whether this is fixed on jquery side or on jquery-ui side. But it has been fixed. Unless you still see the flickering in the link I've just sent.

Comment: Thanks. I have given bounties for your answer. It would be much helpful if you can help me to solve the same issue for this. https://jsfiddle.net/melvinstanly/49cwutg3/

Comment: This seems to be a different issue. I see no flickering there.

Comment: Try to move `test parent` inside `test child` , then flickering happens